# How to supress extra-Line in tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tabbing

is there a way to supress the first line within this tikz-node? So that the text is aligned to the upper-boxframe .

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\node[text width = 5cm,draw=black, rounded corners=3pt, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=.3cm, anchor = west] at  (7,7)
{\begin{tabbing} 
\= \scriptsize \textbf{Topic} \qquad \qquad  \qquad  \=  \scriptsize \textbf{Chapter}   \\
\>\scriptsize \textbullet Topic A \> \scriptsize ref 1 \\
\>\scriptsize \textbullet Topic B\> \scriptsize ref 2  \\
\>\scriptsize \textbullet Topic C\>  \scriptsize ref 3\\
\>\scriptsize \textbullet Topic D \> \scriptsize ref 4
\end{tabbing}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks and greetings
phil

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. Please make your MWE fully compiliable MWE, with its preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! One ad hoc possibility is to add negative vertical space. (It has been a very long time that I have seen `tabbing` in use, are you tied to this option?)

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[text width = 5cm,draw=black, rounded corners=3pt, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=.3cm, anchor = west] at  (7,7)
{\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{tabbing} 
\= \scriptsize \textbf{Topic} \qquad \qquad  \qquad  \=  \scriptsize \textbf{Chapter}   \\
\>\scriptsize \textbullet Topic A \> \scriptsize ref 1 \\
\>\scriptsize \textbullet Topic B\> \scriptsize ref 2  \\
\>\scriptsize \textbullet Topic C\>  \scriptsize ref 3\\
\>\scriptsize \textbullet Topic D \> \scriptsize ref 4
\end{tabbing}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works!  Is there a better solution to organize a  tabbed text node in tikz?

Comment: @phil How about a simple `tabular`?